# Effect of event on average probabilities given different base rates

Tags: bayesian, inference

I am trying to solve the following question with my very rusty stats expertise:

I have a data set of people of which some do exercise with different frequencies per month and other don’t exercise at all (base rates of exercise). My data contains all the dates when each person did exercise. 
At some known point (or multiple times) some people go to a physio/doctor and get told to do exercise – this event is independent if they do exercise by themselves anyway. Some of the people who were told to exercise, do exercise in the week after the visit.
I would like to calculate the impact the visit to physio/doc has on exercise the week after a visit. I was thinking of increase of average probability of exercise the week after the visit, but I am flexible to use other sensible measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for can be formulated as:

$$Imp := \frac
{p(E|P,D=1)}
{p(E|P,D=0)}
$$

Where $Imp$ is Impact of the recommendation, $E$ is Exercising (to a minimum acceptable level at least), $P$ is a patient and $D$ is a binary-valued 'got a Doctor's recommendation or not'.

With the notation out of the way, time to model. Since we're only caring about passing a minimum threshold in just one period at any time, we can model Exercise as a Bernoulli-distributed variable.

Next, we could say that whether they do exercise or not depends on either Patient-specific baseline factors (inclination, health, free time, whatever) and the Doctor's recommendation independently.

That is, if you kidnapped a random person off the street for a checkup, the checkup itself does not itself affect their odds of exercising. If the visit entailed chopping the Patient's leg off, then this assumption would not hold, as it's harder to exercise leg-less.

So with that in mind, $p(E|P,D) = p(E|P)p(P) + p(E|D)p(D)$. Therefore:

$$
Imp = \frac
{ p(E|D=1)p(D=1) + p(E|P)p(P) }
{ p(E|D=0)p(D=0) + p(E|P)p(P) }
$$

If we assume that *not* making a recommendation has no impact on people's lifestyles, i.e. $p(E|D=0)p(D=0)=0$ that leaves us with:

$$
Imp = \frac
{ p(E|D=1)p(D=1) + p(E|P)p(P) }
{ p(E|P)p(P) }
$$

If you're familiar with the formula for the mean of a Beta distribution, it looks a lot of like the reciprocal of this: $\mu_{Beta} = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$.

This makes sense - if we flipped the question to 'how much *fewer* people would exercise if not given the recommendation', we'd wind up with some fraction of the total amount of people who would have exercised given proper encouragement.

So, the simplest solution is to do just that - fit $Imp^{-1}$ as a Beta then invert the fraction to get your target value.

$p(E|P)p(P)$ is the ratio of the pre-treatment exercisers to all patients, $p(E|D=1)p(D=1)$ is the ratio of post-treatment exercises to all *exercisers*, and both are something you can calculate from your data, probably fairly easily at that.

The nice thing about Beta is that in cases like that, you could probably even calculate some small samples on paper if you're fine with just a point estimate of the mean.

Comment: Thank you @jkm . I am struggling to understand p(E|P,D)=p(E|P)p(P)+p(E|D)p(D), although I understand that it must have to do with the independence of patients inclination of exercise and doctors recommendation. Could you possibly point me to some material to read up on to understand this step?

Comment: This is pretty much just an assumption of the model. If we decompose the total factor of want-to-workout-ness into two independent sources, then, well. they are independent by definition. If for some reason this assumption does not hold, then the model will be incorrect.